# Opening huge multi page tiff file as bitmap

Tags: c#

I am trying to open big tiff file as bitmap and display into a picture box control in c# frame work 3.5. I am not able to allocate huge memory to int array. How to allocate huge memory.

Comment: First how big is the file?,second if you are getting an exception maybe because of incompatible file format.

Comment: At present I am trying to open file of size 500 MB but want to open bigger files as well later. Allocation of int[] of Width * height which is like very big is failing.

Comment: I am trying to allocate int[] raster = new int[height * width]; tif.ReadRGBAImage(width, height, raster); where width = 30000 and height = 13500 throwing 'System.OutOfMemoryException' I am using BitMiracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used BitMiracle and opened each tile and combined it into one image

[BitMiracle ReadRGBATile the Image quality is not good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655093/bitmiracle-readrgbatile-the-image-quality-is-not-good/20856323#20856323)